# Is it possible to pass a variable out of a class without creating a new object in C++

Tags: c++, oop, class

I have a variable, which is a member of one of my classes, that another is in need of, but I'm not sure how to effectively pass the value between them without using a global variable, which is something I'd like to avoid if at all possible. I know I could create an object, but that would invoke the constructor of the originating class which would execute a number of functions and write the needless results to memory, which would be wasteful of system resources.

Is there an easy way to pass this value between the two functions?

---

**Update**: The class that is in need of the variable, called `no_of_existing_devices`. The purpose of `class Initialise` is to open up a file and count the number of lines of test it contains, and place that number in the variable `int no_of_existing_devices`, which is then used by the `Device::Device()` to create an object for each

```
class Device
{   
public:
    void view_attribute_list(); 
    void set_attribute();
    Device();
};

Device::Device()
{
    for (int count = 0; count < no_of_existing_devices; count ++)
    {
    // Create an object for each iteration, up to a maximum of no_of_existing_devices
    }
}
```

The class of which this variable is a member

```
class Initialise
{
public:
    int no_of_existing_devices;
    bool initialisation;
    string existing_device_list[100];

    void initialise_existing_devices();
    Initialise();
};

Initialise::Initialise()
{
    no_of_existing_devices = 0;
}

void Initialise::initialise_existing_devices()
{
    string line;
    ifstream DeviceList;
    DeviceList.open("devices/device_list");
    while (true)
    {
        getline(DeviceList, line, '\n');
        if (DeviceList.eof())
        {
            break;
        }
        ++ no_of_existing_devices;
    }
    DeviceList.close();

    DeviceList.open("devices/device_list");
    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_existing_devices; i ++)
    {
        getline(DeviceList, line, '\n');
        existing_device_list[i] = line;
    }

    Device existing_devices[no_of_existing_devices];
    !initialisation; // Existing devices are now initialised
}
```

Comment: Is this variable meant to be a member field of which ever class contains it? Does it depend on the existence of an instance, or can it exist alone?

Comment: can you post your code so that we can get more understanding of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You will have to post more code so that we can understand what you wish to achieve.

Comment: The question has been updated with the code for the two classes in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, from what I understand:

1. You don't want to have a global
2. You don't want to have a static
3. You don't want to introduce a dependency between `Device` and `Initialise`

There is one other option, assuming something *owns* `Device` and `Initialise`, move the `no_of_existing_devices` up to there, then construct both `Device` and `Initialise` with a reference to this variable...

Answer (score 0):

In a similar circumstance I was just passing the pointer to the member --- I had to invoke a member function then, so it was a pointer to the member function, http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html
It's a bit messy, but it works :-).

Answer (score 0):

If the variable in the originating class can hold a value without an instance of the class I would assume that the variable is static. If not create a public static member of the class. And use it in the target class.
Something like:

```
// .h file

class A 
{
   public:
       static int a;
}

// .cpp file

int A::a = 123;

// .cpp file of class B

void B::foo()
{
  cout << A::a;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is a class attribute (internal variable), then you can obtain a reference through a get method. Otherwise, you can use the `friend` keyword on the class you want to access the attribtue from the other For example, if you declare `friend class B;` on class A, the attributes of the class B will be accessible on the class A.

I suggest you use the first method in order to maintain your code OO pure ;)

**Edit:** of course, if you access through a reference there are no resources wasted :)

**Edit 2:** use a static method on `Initialise` class that returns the `no_of_existing_devices` and call `Initialise::NoOfExistingDevices()` on the `Device` class. If you want to resources use a pointer like this:

```
public static int* Initialise::NoOfExistingDevices() {
    return &no_of_existing_devices;
}
```

By the way, I advise you to turn the variable `private`.